# Minimize connection time between two servers

Tags: client-server, latency

(This is a decentralized network)So I'm thinking about how to minimize the time it takes for setting up a connection between two servers. Server A needs to connect to server B to send information forward and back so that they can help its clients as fast as possible. Other than using a client as a relay to speed things up if need be(in which case how would I check whether it would be faster to do it that way if more than two servers are connected and need to send info to its clients) are there any other ways that we could minimize latency?

Note: connections can be made beforehand so as to remove the initial latency when connecting but that still wont reduce the time it takes for information to get from point A to point B

Details:

- Server A has x clients
- Server B has x clients
- A and B have to synchronize the information between all of the
  clients where changes to that information occur at relatively often
  basis (in terms of seconds)
- A and B initially haven't made a connection but know that they have
  to and will do so via any way given (say via a direct connection or
  using a client as a relay or Insert your answer here)

what is the best way to minimize the time it takes to send a packet 
   from point A to point B?

Comment: That is not a neural network.  I would suggest a different tag, but I also think this is off topic for SO.

Comment: Can you add a bit more specific illustration of your problem, perhaps sequence diagram? It is a bit to abstract, at least to me.

Comment: ah ... ok ill change the tag, although a neural network is pretty much a decentralized network

Comment: That is not what makes a [tag:neural-network], which are about artificial learning.